# Is it even possible to rigorously define sine and cosine using the "traditional" definition?

Tags: geometry, reference-request

Most rigorous definitions of the sine and cosine function use power series or some other analytic definition. In geometry class, we learn about the geometric, right-triangle definition of sine and cosine. It is hard to formalize the geometric definition in a rigorous, non-circular (pardon the pun) way. But has anyone done it? Is it even possible to do so? I would be interested in a text or paper that defines the trigonometric functions in a **geometric** way, but rigorously.

Comment: how you checked Michael Spivak's Calculus? He has a Chapter on Trigonometric functions and i think he's approach is what you are asking for.

Comment: What's "non rigorous" in the [usual unit-circle definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Unit-circle_definitions)?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca You have to first rigorously define angle measure.

Comment: I don't think defining the measure of an angle is more difficult than defining the length of a segment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The integral expressing arc length on a unit circle from the point $(1,0)$ up to $(x,\sqrt{1-x^2})$ is arc-sine, etc.